# Как получить выборку из таблицы по внешнему ключу

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Входе получения данных из таблицы по внешнему ключу laravel  выдаёт ошибку: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::all().

Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить ? 
(код программы приведён ниже)

```
class Menu_chapters extends Model
{
    public function chaptersPunkt(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Chapters_punkts','IdChapters');
   }
}

class Chapters_punkts extends Model
{
    public function menuChapters(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Menu_chapters', 'IdChapters');
   }
}

class MenuController extends Controller
{ 
public static function route(Request $request){ 
  $infoMenuChapters = Menu_chapters::all();
  $infoChaptersPunkts=Menu_chapters::find(1)->chaptersPunkt()->where('Chapters_punkts.IdChapters','=','Menu_chapters.id')->all();
 return view('menu')->with(['menuChapters'=>$infoMenuChapters,
                            'menuChapterPunkts'=>$infoChaptersPunkt]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
$infoChaptersPunkts = Menu_chapters::find(1)->chaptersPunkt;
```

Если вы правильно определили отношения, то в `$infoChaptersPunkts` будет коллекция моделей Chapters_punkts.

У вас не совсем обычный подход к именованию. Обычно все классы в Laravel (включая модели) именуются в CamelCase, а названия столбцов в таблицах БД - в snake_case нотациях.

Comment: Да,вся коллекция пунктов выводиться. Но к каждому разделу нужно выводить только часть пунктов, кторые с ним связаны по внешнему ключу - его Id, а не всю коллекцию. (что пытался сделать в выше указанном коде).

Comment: Правильная hasMany должна выводить только принадлежащие родительскому объекту значения. Значит, вы hasMany неправильно описали.

Comment: Хорошо, буду разбираться. Как вариант "костыля"  - использовать ваш метод , а в шаблоне старницы прописать условие вывода  пунктов при совпадении id раздела и внешнего ключа пункта